# my shader is ignoring my worldspace height

Tags: unity-game-engine, fragment-shader

Im VERY new to shaders so bear with me. I have a mesh that I want to put a sand texture on below a worldspace position y of say 10 else it should be a grass texture. Apparantly it seems to be ignoring anything I put in and only selecting the grass texture. Something IS happening because my vert and tris count explodes with this function, compared to if I just return the same texture. I just dont see anything no matter what my sandStart value is

this is in my frag function:

```
if (input.positionWS.y < _SandStart) {
return tex2D(_MainTex, input.uv)* mainLight.shadowAttenuation;
} else {
return tex2D(_SandTex, input.uv) * mainLight.shadowAttenuation;
}
```

Is there also a way I can easily debug some of the values?

Comment: Debugging values in shaders is a pain, colours are pretty much your safest bet. I'd recommend trying this to find out if its the `input.positionWS.y`, `< _SandStart` or `return tex2D` part at fault. 1) what does it look like if you return the y position as its red value? `return float4 (input.positionWS.y, 0,0,1)` (make sure to normalize or divide by some value so it falls somehwere in a 0 > 1 range). This way you can see the current `.y` value as an intensity of red. 2) Replace the `return tex2D` by some flat colours like `return float4(1,0,0,1)` else `return float4(0,1,01)` (checks the if)

Comment: thanks - thats a good idea using colors :) ill try that

Comment: thanks a lot, that debugging method was great, was just a wrong assignment of a number in my geometry function. Throw an answer for debugging and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Please note that the OP figured out that their specific problem wasn't caused by the code in the question, but an error in their geometry function, this answer is only about the question "Is there a way to debug shader values" as this debugging method helped the OP find the problem</sub>

---

Debugging shader code can be quite a challenging task, depending on what it is you need to debug, and there are multiple approaches to it. Personally the approach I like best is using colours.

if we break it down there are three aspects in your code that could be faulty:

- the value of `input.positionWS.y`
- the if statement `(input.positionWS.y < _SandStart)`
- Returning your texture `return tex2D(_MainTex, input.uv)* mainLight.shadowAttenuation;`

Lets walk down the list and test each individually.

1. checking if `input.positionWS.y` actually contains a value we expect it to contain. To do this we can set any of the RGB channels to its value, and just straight up returning that.

```
return float4(input.positionWS.y, 0, 0, 1);
```

Now if `input.positionWS.y` isn't a normalized value (a.k.a a value that ranges from 0 to 1) this is almost guaranteed to just return your texture as entirely red. To normalize it we divide the value by its max value, lets take `max = 100` for the exmaple.

```
return float4(input.positionWS.y / 100, 0, 0, 1);
```

This should now make the texture full red at the top (where `input.positionWS.y / 100` would be 1) and black at the bottom (where `input.positionWS.y / 100` is zero), and a gradient from black to full red inbetween. (Note that since its a position in world space you may need to move the texture up/down to see the colour shift). If this doesn't happen, for example it always stays black or full red then your issue is most likely the `input.positionWS.y`.

2. The if statement. It could be that your statement `(input.positionWS.y < _SandStart)` always returns either `true` or `false`, meaning it'll never split. We can test this quite easily by commenting out the current return texture, and instead just return a flat colour like so:

```
if(input.positionWS.y < _SandStart)
{
    return float4(1,0,0,1);
}
else
{
    return float4(0,0,1,1);
}
```

if we tested the `input.positionWS.y` to be correct in step 1, and `_SandStart` is set correctly we should see the texture be divided in parts red (if true) and the other part blue (if false) (again since we're basing off world position we might need to change the material's height a bit to see it). If this division in colours doens't happen then the likely cause is that `_SandStart` isn't set properly, or to an incorrect value. (assuming this is a property you can inspect its value in the material editor)

3. if both of above steps yield the expected result then `return tex2D(_MainTex, input.uv)* mainLight.shadowAttenuation;` is possibly the culprit. To debug this we can return one of the textures without the if statement and shadowAttenuation, see if it applies the texture, and then return the other texture by changing which line is commented.

```
return tex2D(_MainTex, input.uv);
//return tex2D(_SandTex, input.uv);
```

If each of these textures gets applied properly seperately then it is unlikely that that was your cause, leaving either the shadowAttenutation (just add the multiplication to the above test) or something different altogether that isn't covered by the code in your question.

4. bonus round. If you got a shader *property* you want to debug you can actually do this from C# as well using the `material.Get<type>` function (the supported types can be found in the [docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html), and include the array variants too, as well as both `Get` and `Set`). a small example:

```
Properties 
{
_Foo ("Foo", Float) = 2
_Bar ("Bar", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}
```

can be debugged from C# using

```
Material mat = getComponent<Material>();
Debug.LogFormat("_Foo value: {0}",  mat.GetFloat("_Foo"); //prints 2
Debug.LogFormat("_Bar value: {0}",  mat.GetFloat("_Bar"); //prints (1,1,1,1)
```